# Finding non-continuous numbers in an array

Tags: for-loop, masking, contiguous

I was wondering if you had a column like

[8 8 8 8 8 **1** 4 4 4 1 1]'

What code could I write to find the numbers that are not repeated consecutively (non-contiguous)? In this case, what code would I have to write to find row 6? This is for big data.

--Dwight

Comment: Can you clear your question what is input and output?

Comment: Try for loop with check if actual number is equal to the previous and next numbers.